# How to replace MTLTexture getBytes:bytesPerRow:fromRegion:mipmapLevel: with MTLBlitCommandEncoder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, metal, metalkit

the apple doc of MTLTexture [getBytes:bytesPerRow:fromRegion:mipmapLevel:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexture/1515751-getbytes?language=objc) say

> Don't use this for textures with a private storage mode. To copy data
>   from a private texture, use a MTLBlitCommandEncoder to copy the data
>   from the private texture to another texture that has a non-private
>   storage mode and then copy the data from that texture.

Does someone can gave me an example of how I can replace my `getBytes:bytesPerRow:fromRegion:mipmapLevel:` by a `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` .